# Однородные члены, связанные подчинительным союзом

Tags: союзы, однородные-члены, подчинительная-связь

> Случай исключительный, если не единственный в своём роде.

В данном примере, как я понял, двусоставное полное предложение с однородными сказуемыми *исключительный* и *не единственный*. Однако везде пишут, что подчинительные союзы соединяют лишь неравноправные простые предложения. Где правда?

(Если что, вопрос рассматривается для ЕГЭ)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Случай исключительный, **если не** единственный в своём роде.*

(Самый близкий вариант по смыслу: *Случай исключительный, **даже** единственный в своём роде.*)

Это однородные сказуемые, но однородные отношения осложнены союзом **ЕСЛИ НЕ** (со значением усиленного допущения).

**Пояснение**

В наше время пишут многие и  пишут по-разному, поэтому выбор правильной информации для современного человека очень важен. Всегда нужно оценивать достоверность источника, и это приходится делать самому.

1. Цитируете вы, как я понимаю,  **Розенталя:** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100
   (5). Между однородными членами предложения, соединенными посредством противительных союзов а, но, да (в значении ‘но’), однако, зато и др., подчинительных союзов (уступительных, условных) хотя, если, пусть, ставится запятая:  Да, это был прекрасный, хотя и несколько печальный город (Пауст.); Случай исключительный, если не единственный в своём роде.
2. Розенталь – это справочник по правописанию, а наше правописание тесно связано с **грамматикой.** К сожалению,  у нас нет общедоступного школьного грамматического справочника, поэтому приходится пользоваться дополнительной литературой. Я всем предлагаю вузовский учебник Кустовой, доступная электронная версия 2005 года, но в продаже есть новые доработанные издания (2013, 2017,  2019 года). http://www.1variant.ru/content/uchebniki/russki-yazik/249.pdf

Там можно найти  дополнительный материал  **о типах отношений между однородными членами:**

«Члены ряда могут быть полностью **равноправными или синтаксически дифференцированными.** Дифференцировать отношения между членами ряда могут частицы, наречия и наречные обороты, модальные слова: особенно, может быть, главное, даже, и т.п. Осложняющими являются отношения обусловленности — причинно-следственное или уступительное:  Например: Он купается в озере летом, осенью и даже зимой; Этот маяк более высокий и поэтому более заметный; Яблоки очень вкусные, хоть и не очень крупные.

3. **В толковом словаре Ефремовой** указано: [https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/если_не](https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B5)
   **ЕСЛИ НЕ, союз.**  Употребляется при присоединении однородного члена предложения со значением усиленного допущения, соответствуя по значению сл.: а может быть и.